# SCSS расположение кругов с процентными координатами

Tags: css, scss

Добрый день уважаемые. Столкнулся с проблемой, не получается расположить круги, координаты которых заданы в процентах. Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/cchp53jt/

```css
$colorMain1: rgba(253,225,6, .5); 
$colorMain2: rgba(255,0,0, .5);

@mixin gradient($top, $bottom, $direction: false) {

 @if $direction {
  background: $direction; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient($direction, $top 0%, $bottom 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient($direction, $top 0%, $bottom 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient($direction, $top 0%, $bottom 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient($direction, $top 0%, $bottom 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to $direction, $top 0%, $bottom 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
  } @else {
   background: $top; /* Old browsers */
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, $top 0%, $bottom 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, $top), color-stop(100%, $bottom)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $top 0%, $bottom 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, $top 0%, $bottom 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, $top 0%, $bottom 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $top 0%, $bottom 100%); /* W3C */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
  }

 }

 body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
 }

.bigBlock{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  perspective: 2500px;
  z-index: 1;
  .circle{
   position: absolute;
   width: calc(25%);
   height: 50%;
   border-radius: 50%; 
   z-index: 20;
  
  } 
 }

.Left{
  top: 75%;
  left: 75%;
  transform-origin: right center;
  @include gradient ($colorMain1, $colorMain2, right);

 @for $i from 2 through 4 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
   // animation: rotationCircle 900ms  infinite;
   left: 75% - (12.5*$i);
   transform: scale(1 - 0.125* $i);
  }
 }   
}

.Right{ 
 top: 75%;
 left: 100%;
  transform-origin: right center;
  @include gradient ($colorMain1, $colorMain2, right);

 @for $i from 2 through 4 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
   left: 100% +(12.5*$i);
   transform: scale(1 - 0.125* $i);
  }
 }  
}
```

```html
 <div class="bigBlock">
      <div class="circle Right"></div>
   <div class="circle Right"></div>
   <div class="circle Right"></div>
   <div class="circle Right"></div>
      
      <div class="circle Left"></div>
   <div class="circle Left"></div>
   <div class="circle Left"></div>
   <div class="circle Left"></div>

  </div>
```

Не могу понять почему не высчитывает левые круги, хотя системность задаю такую же что и с правыми, причём если оставить ТОЛЬКО круги с классом left то оно их отрисовывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в счете `nth-child`. Т.к. у вас в начале стоят 4 блока `.Right`, то индексация у `.Left` будет начинаться с 5, т.е. достаточно поменять

```
.Left{
    top: 75%;
    left: 75%;
    transform-origin: right center;
    @include gradient ($colorMain1, $colorMain2, right);

    @for $i from 2 through 4 {
        &:nth-child(#{$i+3}) { // <- смещение от .Right
            // animation: rotationCircle 900ms  infinite;
            left: 75% - (12.5*$i);
            transform: scale(1 - 0.125* $i);
        }
    }           
}
```

и всё [заработает](https://jsfiddle.net/cchp53jt/1/)